# Can WAC 2013 (on-premises) Preview documents crawled from SharePoint 2010 sites

Tags: 2010, 2013, search

I have seen *hints* that this is possible, but many of my resources tell me this is not possible. They also tell me you are the master of all things WAC and have tried this if anyone has. I also have seen a presentation http://www.slideshare.net/BobGerman/search-first-migration-using-sharepoint-2013-search-for-sharepoint-2010 hinting it's possible by modifying the search results templates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is. Have you seen this article referenced by Bob and Max? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murads/archive/2012/10/11/utilizing-web-apps-2010-to-get-powerpoint-previews-of-sharepoint-2010-content-from-sharepoint-2013-search.aspx

There is a lot of Display Template work involved, but it appears that you create a display template that uses the 2010 preview features.